# Lenovo USB 3.0 Ethernet adapter (MacBook PRO)

Tags: network, usb, ethernet

I have a [Deltaco USB 3.0 hub](http://s3.pji.nu/product/standard/800/1865744.jpg) which I've connected a [Thinkpad USB 3.0 Ethernet Adapter](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd029741).

When I boot, or wake, my MacBook Pro (late 2013) won't detect the network interface to be connected at all. I have to re-plug it on the Deltaco USB hub, and 3-5 seconds later I'm up and running.

What I'm wondering is how do I fix this?

While I'm at it, since I use an Apple server for setting date & time, my clock is skewed by +2 hours (I assume it's displaying the wrong timezone or something) when booting. Is there any way to fix this (unless there's a solution to my first question)?

Comment: From my experience, the only USB <> Ethernet adaptors which have very few, if any, problems are Apple branded. Some adaptors flat out don't work; some fail randomly. Having a hub in the chain may also be problematical. The USB <> Ethernet adaptor might work better in a dedicated USB port on the MBP. As for the skewed time, make sure you uncheck the 'Set time zone automatically....' checkbox in the Date & Time System Preference, change the time zone to something random, QUIT System Preferences, go back to Date & Time and set the timezone manually. This may flush out some corrupt prefs.

Answer (score 1):

About the time issue. It was due to dual booting into Windows.

[This guide](http://lifehacker.com/5742148/fix-windows-clock-issues-when-dual-booting-with-os-x) will help you fix it.